# unused arguments when creating a tibble

Tags: r, tibble

```r
my_tibble_1 <- tibble(
  nums = c(4, 5, 6),
  chars = c("hej", " 你好", " こんにちは"),
  cplxnums = c("4+8i", "3+5i", "3+4i") 
)
```

Error in c(4, 5, 6) : unused arguments (5, 6)

Comment: Works fine on my end. Not sure what the issue is. Did you run the entire code after loading `library(tidyverse)`?

Comment: That error makes it sound like you've defined another function named `c()`, overwriting the base R `c()`. I'd suggest trying `rm(c)`

Comment: Exactly the case! thank u so much